# Having two notices of undefined index

Tags: php

I have this code below to insert in my *Admins* table the data that I store when when I fills the fields.

The insert is working fine, but Im having two notices and I´m trying to solve this but Im not finding a good method.

Somebody there can give a little help?

**the two notices Im having:**

-> Undefined index: date in  $insertAdmin->bindValue(':avatar', $f['avatar']);

-> Undefined index: date in  $insertAdmin->bindValue(':date_register', $f['date']);

**My code:**

```
 if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
    {
    $f['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $f['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    //$f['avatar'] = $_POST['avatar'];
    $f['date'] = $_POST['date_register'];

    if(in_array('',$f))
    {
    echo 'Please, fill all fields.';
    }
    else
    {
      if(!empty($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']))
      {
         $image = $_FILES['avatar'];
         $tmp = $imagem['tmp_name'];
         $folder = '../uploads/avatars/';
         $ext = substr($image['name'],-3);
         $name = md5(time()).'.'.$ext;
         $f['avatar'] = $name;
         uploadImage($tmp, $name, '200', $folder);
    }

         $insertAdmin = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO admin (name, email, avatar, date_register) VALUES (:name, :email, :avatar, :date_register)");
         $insertAdmin->bindValue(':name', $f['name']);
         $insertAdmin->bindValue(':email', $f['email']);
         $insertAdmin->bindValue(':avatar', $f['avatar']);
         $insertAdmin->bindValue(':date_register', $f['date']);    
    }
    }
```

My form:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label class="line">
     <span class="data">Name:</span>
     <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($f['name'])) echo $f['name'] ; ?>" />
   </label>


   <label class="line">
    <span class="data">Email:</span>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php  if(isset($f['email'])) echo $f['email'] ; ?>" />
   </label>

   <label class="line">
    <span class="data">Avatar:</span>
    <input type="file" class="fileinput" name="avatar" size="60" />
   </label>

   <label class="line">
    <span class="data">Date of register:</span>
    <input type="text" name="date_register" id="date" value="<?php if(isset($f['date'])) echo $f['date']; else echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s');?>" />
   </label>

   <input type="submit" value="Register" name="sendForm"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen, since you're doing `$f['date'] = ...` above. Are you SURE those are the warnings?

Comment: I think also that is strange, but yes, Im getting this 2 warnings!

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);` ?

Comment: With that output I have my array with the values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no valid reason to have the $f variable, it just makes it confusing.
I would personaly use the POST directly

```
 if(isset($_POST['sendForm']
    isset($_POST['name']   &&
    isset($_POST['email']  &&
    isset($_POST['avatar'] &&
    isset($_POST['date']   &&){
   //Insert
 }else{
   //please fill out everything
 }
```

then execute like this

```
 $insertAdmin = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO admin (name, email, avatar, date_register) VALUES (:name, :email, :avatar, :date_register)");
 $insertAdmin->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
 $insertAdmin->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
 $insertAdmin->bindValue(':avatar', $_POST['avatar']);
 $insertAdmin->bindValue(':date_register', $_POST['date']);
 //do not forget to execute
 $insertAdmin->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with that method! But I still think that its strange didnt work with my method.

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling error:

```
$f['date'] = $_POST['data_register'];
```

Needs to be:

```
$f['date'] = $_POST['date_register'];
//----------------------^
```

Which explains why `$f['date']` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, but its not the problem! Doing the translation I forget to change that part. Sorry!

Comment: I have that line commented because I validate $f['avatar'] after when the file is not empty! Cause I dont want that avatar is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

```
use below an check again.

if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
{
$f['name']   = $_POST['name'];
$f['email']  = $_POST['email'];
$f['avatar'] = $_POST['avatar'];
$f['date']   = $_POST['date_register'];

if(in_array('',$f))
{
echo 'Please, fill all fields.';
}
else
{
  if(!empty($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']))
  {
     $image = $_FILES['avatar'];
     $tmp = $imagem['tmp_name'];
     $folder = '../uploads/avatars/';
     $ext = substr($image['name'],-3);
     $name = md5(time()).'.'.$ext;
     $f['avatar'] = $name;
     uploadImage($tmp, $name, '200', $folder);
}

     $insertAdmin = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO admin (name, email, avatar, date_register) VALUES (:name, :email, :avatar, :date_register)");
     $insertAdmin->bindValue(':name', $f['name']);
     $insertAdmin->bindValue(':email', $f['email']);
     $insertAdmin->bindValue(':avatar', $f['avatar']);
     $insertAdmin->bindValue(':date_register', $f['date']);    
}
}
```

Comment: you have commented  $f['avatar'] = $_POST['avatar']; and there is mistake in getting form variable $f['date'] = $_POST['date_register'];